# Verify Bitcoin transfer from one address to another address in Django

Tags: django, bitcoin

I have a websites which provides a selling platform for individuals. Each individual registers with his bitcoin address and has to input his transaction ID after each transaction. 
My code -

```
import urllib
import re
urlr = "https://blockchain.info/q/txresult/"+hash+"/"+receiver.bitcoin_account
urls = "https://blockchain.info/q/txresult/"+hash+"/"+sender.bitcoin_account
try:
    res = urllib.urlopen(urls)
    resread = res.read()
    sen = urllib.urlopen(urlr)
    senread = sen.read()
except IOError:
    resread = ""
    senread = ""

try:
    resread = int(resread)
    senread = int(senread)
    if resread >= 5000000 and senread != 0:
        ...
```

Please i need a better solution, if i can get

Answer (score 2):

You may get a better result if you run `bitcoind` yourself, and do not rely on blockchain.info's API. Simply start `bitcoind` with the following options:

```
bitcoind -txindex -server
```

If you already synced with the network before you might need to include `-reindex` on the first time.
You will then be able to use the JSON-RPC interface to query for transactions:

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b
```

Better yet, you can use the [`python-bitcoinlib`](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib) library to query and parse the transaction without shelling out to `bitcoin-cli`.

```
from binascii import unhexlify
from bitcoin.rpc Proxy
p = Proxy("http://rpcuser:rpcpass@127.0.0.1:8332")
h = unhexlify("4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b")
print(p.gettransaction(h))
```

That should give you direct access to a local copy of the Bitcoin blockchain, without having to trust blockchain.info, and be faster and more scalable.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply sir, i appreciate. The buyer provides his transaction ID after the payment. How am i going to use the transaction ID to verify that he really paid to the sellers account using python-bitcoinlib.

Comment: My bad, the `gettransaction` call expects the binary hash not the hex-encoded hash, so we need to use `unhexlify` first. Then you should just get a dict with all the relevant data, including a `confirmations` key which tells you how many confirmations this transaction received. Depending on value 2-6 confirmations should suffice.